# How to enable php_mssql and php_pdo_mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp

I have an old project that uses php_mssql and php_pdo_mssql and I want to run it on a wamp server with PHP 5.5.12. I downloaded the following dlls:

- php_mssql.dll (wamdir\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext)
- php_pdo_mssql.dll (wamdir\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext)
- ntwdblib.dll (wamdir\bin\php\php5.5.12)

I added the following lines to php.ini:

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

And finally enabled the php_sybase_ct extension (read it somewhere)
Though I can see php_mssql and php_pdo_mssql checked in php extensions list in wamp, the extensions doesn't work and it gives this error when I test it:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

I run `phpinfo();` and I can't see php_mssql and php_pdo_mssql anywhere.

Please Help.

Comment: Did you restarted the server? Are the extensions inside your php/ext folder?

Comment: @Stanimir yes and yes.

Comment: Do those DLL match your set up? Architecture, thread safety and VC runtime?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario how can I check that ?

Comment: Well... It's normally mentioned in the download page, often in the file name. E.g.: `php_memcache-3.0.8-5.6-nts-vc11-x86.zip`

Comment: If you start from this [PHP Manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php) it walks you through whats required and what to do/install. All you need to know on top of that is that you need the **thread safe** versions to be compatible with WAMPServer. **The bit you are probably missing** is that you need _Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client_ installed on the PC running PHP as well as the PHP extensions, links to download that are on the PHP manual page

Answer (score 1):

You have to use php_sqlsrv.dll for PHP 5.5 or higher. The builds are unofficial.

Download it from here: https://onedrive.live.com/?id=669EE24817961774%21720&cid=669EE24817961774&group=0&parId=669EE24817961774%21123&o=OneUp

Extract into \standard\ext\

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Extract into \standart-fcgi\ext

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
```

In php.ini

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll  

extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

Comment: This is an entirely different extension :-?

Comment: Yes. Microsoft has an official php_mssql.dll which runs only on php 5.3.

Comment: Well, the thing is I can't lower the php version. And your solution doesn't work, I even can't find those extensions on the php extension list in wamp.

Comment: But both extensions are not interchangeable. Your solution implies a full rewrite of the old project. Is that intentional?

Comment: Not at all. I assume that you can;t find those extensions on the list because they are unofficial.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario you are right I'm not doing that !